# ¿Cómo puedo subir un dato del tipo 'time' desde excel usando la libreía PhpSpreadSheet con php a Mysql?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

[image: la casilla resaltada en amarillo es el dato que quiero leer y guardar en mysql, es la hubicacion]Este es el codigo que estoy manejando. Ayudaaaaa!
todo funciona muy bien, puedo subir la informacion sin problemas, pero al querer insertar una hora desde excel a mysql 'no' lee el dato.

```
$nombreArchivo = "hoja1.xls";

$cargarArchivo = IOFactory::load($nombreArchivo);
$totalHojas = $cargarArchivo->getSheetCount();
$hojaActual = $cargarArchivo->getSheet(0);
$numeroFilas = $hojaActual->getHighestDataRow();
$columnas = $hojaActual->getHighestColumn();
$numeroColumnas = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($columnas);
//por cada fila encontrada leeremos el contenido de la celda
for($indiceFila = 1; $indiceFila <= $numeroFilas; $indiceFila++){
    //aqui se leen las celdas
    $valorF = $hojaActual->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $indiceFila);
// en esta celda necesito leer un valor del tipo time para guardarlo en Mysqli
    $valorG = $hojaActual->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $indiceFila);
//se pasa a insertar valores del archivo excel a mysqli   
}
```

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda que mostraras los datos ejemplo del Excel y la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: Tienes razon hermano, disculpa, acabo de subir una captura de la tabla en la hoja de excel, agradezco la ayudaaaaa!